# Other columns with GROUP BY

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

I've got a PostgreSQL database for weather readings:

```
CREATE TABLE "weather"
  (
  "id" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  "dtstamp" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  "temperature" REAL NOT NULL,
  ...
  } ;
```

I'm getting the daily minimum temperatures:

```
SELECT
  DATE_TRUNC('day'::TEXT, weather.dtstamp) AS dts,
  ROUND((MIN(weather.temperature))::NUMERIC, 1) AS mintemp
FROM weather
GROUP BY (date_trunc('day'::text, weather.dtstamp))
ORDER BY (date_trunc('day'::text, weather.dtstamp)) DESC
LIMIT 28 ;
```

How can I pull out the time(s) that the minimum happened at, and how to cope when if there's more than one time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join weather with the result table over day and tempetarue.

This is the old fashioned way, I'm quite sure there's some neater way with window functions...

```
SELECT 
  DATE_TRUNC('day'::TEXT, w1.dtstamp) AS day,
  dtstamp,
  ROUND(w1.temperature::NUMERIC, 1) AS mintemp
FROM weather w1  
 INNER JOIN 
(SELECT
  DATE_TRUNC('day'::TEXT, wmin.dtstamp) AS dts,
  ROUND((MIN(wmin.temperature))::NUMERIC, 1) AS mintemp
FROM weather wmin
GROUP BY (date_trunc('day'::text, wmin.dtstamp))) w2
  on DATE_TRUNC('day'::TEXT, w1.dtstamp) = w2.dts
     AND ROUND(w1.temperature::NUMERIC, 1) = w2.mintemp
```

This way you get all times with with the (rounded) minimal temerature.

But you could do the rounding only in the final select and have only the records with the float minimal temperature times

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/1281)

Comment: Thanks, that's just what I was looking for. Will do the rounding in the final select, too.